# Memory Leak Analysis in a DCOM Server Developed in VC6

Tags: visual-c++, memory-leaks, mfc, visual-c++-6, dcom

I am developing an age old DCOM Server application and my job is to find the Memory Leaks in that DCOM Server. The DCOM Server application was developed in VC6 and MFC.

Is there any Free tools available to do the Memory Leak analysis?

I have tried to use the UMDH but as the UMDH demands for the Target image(exe),  I am unable to do?

Thanks in advance :)

EDIT 1: I forgot to say that this DCOM Server is a DLL that was hosted through the DCOMCNFG

Comment: What about the built in features in the MFC/CRT debug Version. Are they not sufficient?

Comment: Are you mentioning the crtdbg.h Techniques?

Comment: [VLD](http://vld.codeplex.com/) might be useful.

Comment: Sorry Michael, VLD will not detect COM Leaks